# What is the maximum number of methods on a Python class?

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, methods

I am automatically generating unit tests for some Python code which number in the thousands. The `unittest` module uses classes to contain the tests however I'm guessing there is an upper limit to the number of methods a class may contain - is this the case?

Comment: If you're worried that one of your classes may contain more methods than you could carry in a single class + 2, then you have worse problems than you think.

Comment: I thought there would be because software in general is programmed full of arbitrary limits ... stack size, filename length etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Methods (and in fact *all* attributes) of a class are stored in a `dict`. There is no limit to the number of items a `dict` can contain, save that each key must be unique.

Answer (score 6):

I strongly doubt that you'd ever hit the limit, even if there was one. As far as I know though, the number of methods an object can have is limited only by memory. I just defined a class with a million functions, with no problem. Try this if you don't believe me:

```
>>> class C(object): pass
>>> for i in xrange(10**6):
        exec('C.func%d=lambda self: %d'%(i,i))

>>> c = C()
>>> c.func1()
1
>>> c.func999999()
999999
```

If your class has more than a million functions (hell, or more than a dozen or so), you have other problems.

Comment: Ah I should have thought of trying something like this ... I wouldn't normally have classes with more than a dozen or so methods but the `unittest` paradigm seems to encourage it

Comment: Why would having functions more than dozen be a problem?